# Make C char array from NSString object in Obj-C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, string, nsstring

I want to make a C char array from NSString object in Obj-C.

My string is:

```
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url usedEncoding:nil error:nil];
```

Can someone send me a sample of a working code?

Thanks in advance,

Sagiftw

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`UTF8String`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/UTF8String) method:

```
const char *str = [string UTF8String];
```

Comment: +1, but I don't want the UTF8String encoding, I lose the Hebrew characters using it!

Comment: If you don't want UTF-8 Encoding, use -cStringUsingEncoding: and pass the appropriate encoding.

Comment: You won't lose the Hebrew characters by using UTF8String.  UTF-8 is capable of representing any Unicode character.  If your Hebrew characters are disappearing, the problem is not here.

Comment: what if i dont need const and only char*?

Answer (score 1):

```
NSData *data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

void *bytes = [data bytes];
```

(Credit: [NSString - Unicode to ASCII equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591052/nsstring-unicode-to-ascii-equivalent))

Or as one line:

```
void *bytes = [[string dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES] bytes];
```

Comment: @user318205: If you didn't like the other answer because it loses Hebrew characters, you definitely won't like this one since you'll just get an array of ASCII characters.  There's no Hebrew in ASCII.