# Removing unicode and backslash escapes from NSString converted from NSData

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring, nsdata

I am converting the response data from a web request to an NSString in the following manner:

```
NSData *data = self.responseData;
if (!data) {
    return nil;
}
NSStringEncoding encoding = CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(CFStringConvertIANACharSetNameToEncoding((__bridge CFStringRef)[self.response textEncodingName]));
NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:encoding];
```

However the resulting string looks like this:

```
"birthday":"04\/01\/1990",
"email":"some.address\u0040some.domain.com"
```

What I would like is

```
"birthday":"04/01/1990",
"email":"some.address@some.domain.com"
```

without the backslash escapes and unicode.  What is the cleanest way to do this?

Comment: looks like the response is encoded in json format, then simply use a json decoder like SBJson to get the correct strings

Comment: @phix23 Didn't think of that, parsing the JSON does give the correct form!  Write an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response seems to be JSON-encoded. So simply decode the response string using a JSON library (SBJson, JsonKit etc.) to get the correct form.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace (or remove) characters using NSString's [stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:withString:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) or [stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html).

To remove (convert) unicode characters, use `dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES` (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2591182/793911)).

I'm sorry if the following has nothing to do with your case: Personally, I would ask myself where did that back-slashes come from in the first place. For example, for JSON, I'd know that some sort of JSON serializer on the other side [escapes some characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7597014/793911) (so the slashes are really there, in the response, and that is not a some weird bug in Cocoa). That way I'd able to tell for sure which characters I have to handle and how. Or maybe I'd use [some kind of library](https://github.com/stig/json-framework/) to do that for me.

Comment: Actually, it is related since the response is in JSON.