# Convert NSString with NSScanner

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsscanner

I have a string formatted like this : `Oy\U00e9\U00e9 Oy\U00e9`
So, I found something in some forum and tried to adapt it. This is what I use :

```
// To keep whiteSpaces safe
string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"@@**@@"];
NSMutableString* clean_string = [NSMutableString string];
NSScanner* scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:string];
NSString* buf = nil;

while (![scanner isAtEnd] ) {
    //Plus de caractères à scanner
    if (![scanner scanUpToString: @"\\u" intoString: &buf] ){
        break;
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", buf);
    [clean_string appendString: buf];

    //Fin du scan
    if ([scanner isAtEnd] ){
        break;
    }

    [scanner setScanLocation: [scanner scanLocation] + 3];//skip the '\\u'
    unsigned c = 0;

    if ([scanner scanHexInt: &c]){
        [clean_string appendFormat: @"%c", c];
    }else{
        [clean_string appendString: @"\\u"];//nm
    }
}



self.cleanStringWithSpaces= [clean_string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"@@**@@" withString:@" "];

return self.cleanStringWithSpaces;
```

The problem is that when I have a string with 2 \u00e9 following, the string is cut.

**Example**:

```
Oy\U00e9\U00e9 Oy\U00e9    Give ====> Oyé
```

Instead of : `Oyéé Oyé`

Maybe I missed something ... Hope you could help me !

Have a nice day !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/594797/how-to-use-nsscanner

Comment: Are you *certain* your string contains `\Uxxxx` and that's not just how you are seeing it in logs/etc.?

Comment: Yes I get this like this. I'm sure, but do you know a method to know it without logs ?

Comment: @iPatel, not really what I'm looking for.

Comment: Why does your code scan for lowercase "u" when your input string has uppercase "U"?

Comment: This does not address the code you're trying to use, but the original problem: you might find either [Converting escaped UTF-8 characters back to their original form](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7860867) or [Removing Unicode and backslash escapes from NSString converted from NSData](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9018347) useful.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Thank you very much ! The first link made it ! A lot of thanks to you ! You could post it in an answer, I'll validate it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@JoshCaswell made my day by answer to my question.

I used something I found here : [Converting escaped UTF8 characters back to their original form](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7860867)

```
[NSString stringWithCString:[name2escaped cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
        encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the line:

```
[scanner setScanLocation: [scanner scanLocation] + 3];//skip the '\\u'
```

When changing the scanners location, you are counting the escape character. `@"\\u"` is actually only `\u`, therefore you should use:

```
[scanner setScanLocation: [scanner scanLocation] + 2];//skip the '\\u'
```